# didRegisterUserNotificationSettings Being Called Twice?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, onesignal

I've been having an issue with my iOS app receiving duplicated over ever push notification. After doing some digging around StackOverflow, I figured out the issue could be because `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings` was being called twice.

So, I set a breakpoint on `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings`, and indeed, it is being called twice every time the app is launched.

The problem is, I'm only calling it once! Can someone please help me here and tell me why the delegate method `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings` is being called twice in the use case below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

[OneSignal initWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions appId:@"xxxx"];

return true;
```

}

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    NSString *devToken = [[[[deviceToken description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:devToken forKey:kUserDeviceTokenKey];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //firing twice!
    NSLog("check");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using 1.* version of the SDK. Make sure to update to the latest [2.0.9](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/releases/2.0.9) version to solve this issue.